# How to show PopUp with in the screen area In Flex and AS3

Tags: apache-flex, popup, mouseover

Hi i am trying to show my popup on the image mouse over 
it is showing fine 
when i trying mouse over right side last images popup is going out of the screen
Here **TalentInfoPopUp is **TitleWindow**

This is my sample code

```
private static var staticWindow :TalentInfoPopUp = null;  
private static var visibleWindow:TalentInfoPopUp = null;

public static function show(t:Object, parent : DisplayObject, x:Number , y:Number):void
{
if(staticWindow == null)
{
visibleWindow = staticWindow = PopUpManager.createPopUp( parent , TalentInfoPopUp , false) as TalentInfoPopUp;
    }

    else if(visibleWindow == null)
    { 
        visibleWindow = staticWindow;
        PopUpManager.addPopUp(staticWindow, parent, false);

    }

    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(staticWindow);

    staticWindow.talent = t;
    staticWindow.x = x;
    staticWindow.y =y;      

    PopUpManager.bringToFront(staticWindow);
    staticWindow.talent = t;
    staticWindow.move(x,y);
    staticWindow.callLater(staticWindow.setPosition,[x,y]);
    //staticWindow.setPosition(x,y);

}



private function setPosition(nx:int,ny:int):void
{
    var maxWidth:int =  stage.width ;
    var maxHeight:int = stage.height;

    if(nx>maxWidth-width)
    {
        nx=nx-width;
    }
    if(ny>maxHeight-height)
    {
        ny=ny-height;
    }

    this.move(nx,ny); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `systemManager.screen.width` and `systemManager.screen.height` instead of `stage.width` and `stage.height`; also learn about the `localToGlobal` and `globalToLocal` methods and how to use them.

Comment: Hi thanx for replying this almost working fine after changing to Screen.width and screen.height. 
I am displaying two rows of images in Customized TileList  first row of images the mouse over is working fine. When it comes on second row last image mouse over is coming and hiding its not stable. Is there any wrong in my calculation ?